# After click button and refresh website all buttons are like selected on django detail view

Tags: python, django, listview, many-to-many, django-orm

I have app in django 1.11 and I have problem with voting up or down on comments on detail page of post.

For each I would like to check if is voted up or voted down. Now if I click vote up - jquery code - change only this button on voted up, counter of votes also works ok, but after refresh website all vote up buttons of comments are like voted up.

Below is my code

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextUploadingField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def total_vote_up(self):
        return self.votes_up.count()

    def total_vote_down(self):
        return self.votes_down.count()


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    votes_up = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='up_votes')
    votes_down = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='down_votes')
```

Below is my detail view with comments objects.

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        is_voted_up = False
        is_voted_down = False

        comments = self.get_object().comments.all()
        for comment in comments:
            if comment.votes_up.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                is_voted_up = True
            if comment.votes_down.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                is_voted_down = True

        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.get_object().comments.all()
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'post': self.get_object(), 'author': self.get_user()})
        context['is_voted_up'] = is_voted_up
        context['is_voted_down'] = is_voted_down
        return context
```

Comment: I don't understand that this code works at all: `comment.votes_up.filter(...)` if your `Comment` model doesn't have a `votes_up` field.

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry my mistake, please check now, after my edit.

Comment: What does "all vote up buttons of comments are like voted up" mean? I don't understand the question. Are the votes recorded correctly in the database? Is that the problem? Or are they recorded correctly but not shown correctly?

Comment: Note that you're only setting *one* value `is_voted_up` for the context: if one comment has the vote, and 9 other comments don't have the vote, then is_voted_up = True.

Comment: @dirkgroten Votes are correctly stored in the database. Incorrectly displayed after voting for one and pressing F5. Then they are all voted for, even though I voted for only one. Somehow `is_voted_up` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to annotate your comments when fetching them:

```
votes_by_user = User.objects.filter(
   up_votes__pk=OuterRef('pk'),
   id=self.request.user.id,
)
context['comments'] = self.object.comments.all().annotate(upvoted=Exists(votes_by_user))
```

Then in your template each `comment` will have an attribute `upvoted` telling whether of not the current user upvoted this comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can I also use here `prefetch_related('votes_up', 'votes_down')`?

Comment: Yes you can if you need to get the data of all the other users that voted. But if you're only looking to add a counter, you could just add another annotation which wouldn't require an additional query (prefetch_related performs an additional query).

Comment: can you give me a hint, how can I put `comment.upvoted` into ajax?